# Incomplete form submission due to empty file input values in React, how can I pass data from child to parent components?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

I am working on a React application where I have a form for uploading files. I'm facing an issue where the uploaded file inputs show empty values in the json when i storing the form data , resulting in an incomplete submission.

```
export default function UserNewForm({ isEdit = false, isScholarship = false, currentUser }) {
  const defaultValues = useMemo(() => ({
    aadharCard: null,
    previousYearMarksheet: null,
    bankPassbook: null,
    casteCertificate: null,
    incomeCertificate: null,
    passportSizePhoto: null,
    signature: null,
    tenthMarksheet: null,
    twelfthMarksheet: null,
    graduationMarksheet: null,
  }), []);

  const handleSelectedFile = (event, fieldName, file) => {
    // Handle the selected file here
    // You can set the file in state or perform any other necessary actions
    console.log("Selected file:", file);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("aadharCard", data.aadharCard ? data.aadharCard.name : null);
      formData.append("previousYearMarksheet", data.previousYearMarksheet ? data.previousYearMarksheet.name : null);
      formData.append("bankPassbook", data.bankPassbook ? data.bankPassbook.name : null);
      formData.append("casteCertificate", data.casteCertificate ? data.casteCertificate.name : null);
      formData.append("incomeCertificate", data.incomeCertificate ? data.incomeCertificate.name : null);
      formData.append("passportSizePhoto", data.passportSizePhoto ? data.passportSizePhoto.name : null);
      formData.append("signature", data.signature ? data.signature.name : null);
      formData.append("tenthMarksheet", data.tenthMarksheet ? data.tenthMarksheet.name : null);
      formData.append("twelfthMarksheet", data.twelfthMarksheet ? data.twelfthMarksheet.name : null);
      formData.append("graduationMarksheet", data.graduationMarksheet ? data.graduationMarksheet.name : null);

      if (isScholarship) {
        await axios.post("/formsubmit", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`,
          },
        });
        enqueueSnackbar("Scholarship created!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Your form JSX code */}
      <ScholarshipForm
        title="Aadhar Card"
        name="aadharCard"
        onFileChange={(event, fieldName, file) => handleSelectedFile(event, fieldName, file)}
      />

      <ScholarshipForm
        title="Previous Year Marksheet"
        name="previousYearMarksheet"
        onFileChange={(event, fieldName, file) => handleSelectedFile(event, fieldName, file)}
      />

      {/* Rest of the ScholarshipForm components */}
    </>
  );
}
```

```
const ScholarshipForm = ({ title, name, onFileChange }) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleChangeFile = (event) => {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    setFile(selectedFile);
    onFileChange(event, name, selectedFile);
  };

  return (
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ mb: 1 }}>
        Upload {title}
      </Typography>
      <Button variant="contained" component="label">
        {file ? file.name : "Choose File"}
        <input
          type="file"
          name={name}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={handleChangeFile}
        />
      </Button>
      <br />
      <br />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

i try this

```
const handleSelectedFile = (event, fieldName, file) => {
    // Handle the selected file here
    // You can set the file in state or perform any other necessary actions
    console.log("Selected file:", file);
  };
```

i m trying when i selecting the choose file it get save in json form or show name of the file in json .

Comment: I dont see where you append the file to the formdata and its unclear to me what exactly the issue is. what do you see in the console when you log the file param in handleSelectedFile?